# Is there a jQuery plugin for list sorting?

Tags: jquery-plugins

Is there a jQuery plugin that will allow to sort a list of items (`<li>...</li>`) according to their meta data stored as a hidden element? For instance every list item has two hidden inputs: `author` and `year`. I want sort the list using those hidden elements. I wonder if there is a ready to use plugin for jQuery. So far, I have not found such plugin. The only I have found are for table sorting.

```
<ul>
  <li>Position 1
    <input type="hidden" name="author" value="Peter"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="year" value="2004"/>
  </li>
  <li>Position 2
    <input type="hidden" name="author" value="John"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="year" value="2005"/>
  </li>
  <li>Position 3
    <input type="hidden" name="author" value="Tony"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="year" value="2006"/>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please note that "ul" stands for "Unordered List" :D

Comment: Hah, that is true. However, this list is unsorted in the sense of numbering the items ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<ul>
  <li>Position 1
    <input type="hidden" name="author" value="Peter"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="year" value="2004"/>
  </li>
  <li>Position 2
    <input type="hidden" name="author" value="John"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="year" value="2005"/>
  </li>
  <li>Position 3
    <input type="hidden" name="author" value="Tony"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="year" value="2006"/>
  </li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.fn.sort = function() {  
        return this.pushStack( [].sort.apply( this, arguments ), []);  
    };  

    function mySorter(a,b){  
         return $(a).find("[name=author]").val() > $(b).find("[name=author]").val() ? 1 : -1;  
    };  

    $(document).ready(function(){
         $('ul li').sort(mySorter).appendTo('ul');
    })

</script>
```

I adapted it from: http://www.wrichards.com/blog/2009/02/jquery-sorting-elements/

Edit:fixed error with val() and 'ul'

Comment: @Lance ~ Nice job, I stumbled accross this and it works exaclty as expected!